# Сообщить поисковикам что сайт на обновлении

Tags: веб-программирование, поисковые-системы

Есть какой-либо способ сообщить поисковикам что сайт на обновлении. То есть, страницы временно недоступны и их не выбрасывали из поисковой базы или накладывали другие санкции?

Comment: Предположу (только предположу!) что 503 service temporarily unavailable будет воспринят корректно.

Comment: @Etki, скорее всего, вот что нашёл - https://wireflare.com/seo-for-a-site-that-is-under-construction/

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что никак. Единственный способ - сделать странички under constuction подменяющие все проиндексированные страницы и проверить что роботы гугла и яндекса их видят.